# Aggregation for computing distribution across array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to create an aggregation that will compute the distribution of values across an array of objects and return an array of computed values.

Here is a sample document

```json
[
  {
    "duration": 1208,
    "dataPoints": 2,
    "binMin": 0,
    "binMax": 5000
  },
  {
    "duration": 25735,
    "dataPoints": 3,
    "binMin": 5000,
    "binMax": 10000
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "dataPoints": 0,
    "binMin": 10000,
    "binMax": 20000
  },
  {
    "duration": 54088,
    "dataPoints": 2,
    "binMin": 20000,
    "binMax": 28817
  }
]
```

I need to add up the durations for each object, then compute the distribution across each object and return a new array like so:

```
[
  {
    "duration": 1208,
    "dataPoints": 2,
    "binMin": 0,
    "binMax": 5000,
    "ratio": 0.014907874763979
  },
  {
    "duration": 25735,
    "dataPoints": 3,
    "binMin": 5000,
    "binMax": 10000,
    "ratio": 0.317594500870037
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "dataPoints": 0,
    "binMin": 10000,
    "binMax": 20000,
    "ratio": 0
  },
  {
    "duration": 54088,
    "dataPoints": 2,
    "binMin": 20000,
    "binMax": 28817,
    "ratio": 0.667497624365983
  }
]
```

I am able to calculate the total duration and divide to get the ratio value but it seems to be only doing it to the first element of the array.

This is my aggregation so far:

```
[{$project: {
    _id: '$_id',
    username: 1,
    uuid: 1,
    data: '$stats.dataHistogram'
   }}, {$unwind: {
    path: '$data'
   }}, {$group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    data_bin: {
     $first: '$data'
    },
    total_duration: {
     $sum: '$data.duration'
    }
   }}, {$project: {
    _id: '$_id',
    total_duration: 1,
    data_bin: 1,
    ratio: {
     $divide: [
      '$data_bin.duration',
      {
       $add: [
        '$total_duration',
        1
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
   }}]
```

(I'm adding a 1 to the $total_duration because it can be 0 some times and I get a "Cannot divide by zero" error)

I feel like I'm super close but not sure what the next steps should be. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you are grouping, `$first` retains only the first `$data` value seen.  If you want to see all of them, use `$push`

Comment: it's very unclear what your original structure is, what you posted as your schema does not match the pipeline provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` to compute the total duration first. Then apply element wise `$divide` by using `$map`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "totalDuration": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$stats.histogram",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            $add: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.duration"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "totalDuration": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "$totalDuration",
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": "$totalDuration"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "stats.histogram": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$stats.histogram",
          "as": "h",
          "in": {
            "duration": "$$h.duration",
            "dataPoints": "$$h.dataPoints",
            "binMin": "$$h.binMin",
            "binMax": "$$h.binMax",
            "ratio": {
              "$divide": [
                "$$h.duration",
                "$totalDuration"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qtv0A0fyhee) for your reference.

Comment: Does $lookup work with a nested document? In my case, the array is a child of ```stats.dataHistogram```. I am unable to substitute ```collection``` for it. I can't use an expression for the $lookup as my Atlas tier does not support it.
Also, I'm using this in Compass' Aggregation tool - not sure if it matters.

Comment: @HasanAliKhan Are you looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qtv0A0fyhee)?

Comment: This is amazing! Exactly what I was looking for. What a champ!